# How to make the game continue playing, not just playing once

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

At the moment, the red color circle can be played only once, can the game continue to play maybe for 1 minute, then it will stop and show the scores? And when the following game continues, so the answer to the game will be automatically changed.

It is great that people can run it and see what is happening of the processing. The game is p5.js.
Here is the link: https://editor.p5js.org/mtwhill/sketches/ryMrazX5Q

[image: The picture shows the game interface. They the red ball goes into the red area then it appears, vice versa]

```js
var bx;
var by;
var ellSize = 75;
var overBox = false;
var locked = false;
var xOffset = 0.0; 
var yOffset = 0.0; 

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 300);
  bx = width/2.0;
  by = height/2.0;
  rectMode(RADIUS);
  strokeWeight(1.5);
}

function draw() { 
  background(230);
  
  // Test if the cursor is over the box 
  if (mouseX > bx-ellSize && mouseX < bx+ellSize && 
      mouseY > by-ellSize && mouseY < by+ellSize) {
    overBox = true;  
    if(!locked) { 
      stroke(255); 
    } 
  } else {
    stroke(0);
    overBox = false;
  }
  
  // Draw the box
 fill(250, 0, 0);
  ellipse(bx, by, ellSize, ellSize);
 rect(50, 50, 80, 80);
 fill(0, 250, 0);
 rect(550, 50, 80, 80);
 fill(0, 0, 250);
 rect(50, 250, 80, 80);
 fill(0, 0, 0);
 rect(550, 250, 80, 80);

}

function mousePressed() {
  if(overBox) { 
    locked = true; 
  } else {
    locked = false;
  }
  xOffset = mouseX-bx; 
  yOffset = mouseY-by; 

}

function mouseDragged() {
  if(locked) {
    bx = mouseX-xOffset; 
    by = mouseY-yOffset; 
  }
}

function mouseReleased() {
  if(bx>120|by >120) {
  bx = 300;
  by = 150;
   }
 else {
  ellSize = 0;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example?

Comment: Don't make the understandability of your question depending on links to external sources. They may disappear and your question becomes useless

Comment: Thanks for that, I changed it. It makes easy for people to read.

Comment: When the mouse button is released the you have to set `locked = false;` Further you should use a logical OR instead of a bitwise OR `bx>120 || by>120` instead of `bx>120 | by>120`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, and editing.

Comment: Please link between crossposts. This question has also been asked [here](https://discourse.processing.org/t/how-to-make-the-game-continue-playing-not-just-playing-once/4215).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, once your game is over, it'll pause for a minute then show the scores. After it does that, some answer will then be changed then it'll continue to run again? If that is, you can do something like this:

```
// you'll need to have something change this to true
// You'll use this variable to rerun the game if the user chooses to do so
let gameOver = false 

function draw(){
  // draw your game's elements
   if (/*game over condition*/) {
     gameOver = true;
     // Once gameOver is true, the elements of your game will
     // no longer be drawn and that is when you'll draw the scoreboard
   }
   if(gameOver){
        // Once gameOver is false again, your game will run normally
        showScores();
      } 
}
```

**ShowScores** is where you can have your scoreboard stuff drawn and variables manipulated

```
function showScore(){
  while(counter != 60){
    // introduce some delay so your game will still be displayed for 1 minute
    if(frameCount % 60 == 0){
      counter++;
    }
  }

  // you can also manipulate variables that contain the answer here if you want

  // reset the canvas so stuff won't be drawn over other stuff
  // draw our imaginary scoreboard
  background(255,255,255);
  fill(240,240,240);
  rect(50, 50, 80, 80);

  resetGame();
}
```

**resetGame** is where you'll give the user the option to rerun the game. If he chooses to do so, set `gameOver` to `false` so that the game will be redrawn.

```
function resetGame(){
 // give the user an option to rerun the game
 // then set gameOver to false so that the game's elements will be
 // draw again instead of the scroreboard.
}
```

Here's a [`working example`](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/zmKXWQ?editors=1010) :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, you are right that is what I like the game to do. I played the game that you give the link, but it does not work well. When playing the game, the grey block will appear.

Comment: I've only made it so the block will appear after some number of frames. You'd have to implement a proper mechanism that will tell the game when to stop :)

Comment: Alright. Happy coding! Remember: It'll all remove around the control variable's (`gameOver`) state :)